# Webkit transform doesn't work, what should I do

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, transform

whats the problem with this code? It doesn't work on Google Chrome. I want to rotate the picture dynamically with javascript and webkit transform.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('img1').style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(-40deg)";   
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="img1" src="1.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead - the script needs to be executed after the DOM has loaded - so i have moved it to appear after the `img` element

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="img1" src="1.jpg" />
  <script>
     document.getElementById('img1').style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-40deg)";   
  </script>
</body>
</html>​
```

And your using the wrong webkitTransform function ... you should be using [rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#rotate)

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/5HeG2/)

Answer (score 2):

Rotating over the x-axis is undefined. Use a plain [`rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#rotate) instead. Furthermore, you're trying to refer to an element which does not exist at run-time. Either defer the script load, or:

It's pure CSS, I suggest to replace the whole `<script>` block with:

```
<style>
#img1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
}
</style>
```

Note: This code will only show a rotation in webkit-based browsers. For optimum [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility), don't forget to use the `-moz-`, `-o-` and `-ms-` and prefixless prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

As scripts run immediately when they are loaded, the `script` tag in the `head` of your document has run before the body has been loaded.

If you move the `script` tag to the end of the `body` tag, you should find that it doesn't throw errors.